# Clean way of creating model

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder what is the cleanest way to create model with data which doesn't change during app life.

I want to have model with array like [exerciseTitle:exerciseImage]

Currently I do it in this way:

```
    struct ExerciseCategoriesModel {

        var categories: [ExerciseCategoryModel] = [ExerciseCategoryModel(title: "Chest", image: UIImage(named: "chest")),
        ExerciseCategoryModel(title: "Back", image: UIImage(named: "back")),
        ExerciseCategoryModel(title: "Shoulders", image: UIImage(named: "shoulders")),
        ExerciseCategoryModel(title: "Quads", image: UIImage(named: "quads"))]
    }
    
    struct ExerciseCategoryModel {
        var title: String
        var image: UIImage?
    }
```

And then use it in tableview

```
class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

     var categoriesModel = ExerciseCategoriesModel()
    
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.dataSource = self
      }

      .
      .
      .
      .

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
      .
      .
      .
        cell.label.text = categoriesModel.categories[indexPath.row].title
        cell.rowImage.image = categoriesModel.categories[indexPath.row].image

}
```

What is the proper approach to create model? Creating struct with setted data (like above) or maybe create a service to set data and then call service which return data?

Comment: If the model is immutable then all properties should be `let` declared.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: This is how **I** would design the model

##### `ExerciseCategory` struct

For the base model struct I would opt for immutable properties and simple type name - `Model` suffix only introduces noise in my opinion.

```swift
struct ExerciseCategory {
    let title: String
    let image: UIImage?
}
```

Based on your question it looks like an `enum` would be a good fit

```swift
enum ExerciseCategory: String {
    case back
    case shoulders
    case quads
}

extension ExerciseCategory {
    // a
    var title: String {
        // You better localize your strings :)
        //
        // "back" = "Back";
        // "shoulders" = "Shoulders";
        // "quads" = "Quads";
        //
        NSLocalizedString(rawValue, comment: "")
    }
    // b
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .back:
            return "Back"
        case .shoulders:
            return "Shoulders"
        case .quads:
            return "Quads"
        }
    }
    var image: UIImage? {
        UIImage(named: rawValue)
    }
}
```

##### Introduce a `ExerciseViewModel`

Instead of declaring another `Model` struct I would go for a ViewModel which could be a `final class` so we can take advantage of it being reference type.

```swift
final class ExerciseViewModel {
    let categories: [ExerciseCategory] = [
        ExerciseCategory(title: "Back", image: UIImage(named: "back")),
        ExerciseCategory(title: "Shoulders", image: UIImage(named: "shoulders")),
        ExerciseCategory(title: "Quads", image: UIImage(named: "quads"))
    ]
}
```

or, if you went with enums:

```swift
final class ExerciseViewModel {
    // You can make enums conform to a `CaseIterable` protocol to
    // access them like this: ExerciseCategory.allCases
    let categories: [ExerciseCategory] = [
        .back, .shoulders, .quads
    ]
}
```

Here you will need to ask yourself: what is the data I am showing here? Is it something static like a settings screen? Or is it something more dynamic like a genres of movies fetched from a server? For the latter part I would recommend analysing the fetched data and showing the categories based on the results you are showing.

##### ViewController implementation

Now we can add `viewModel` property to our ViewController. I like to trigger a view reload on `didSet` co in theory the view can be populated with different data at any time.

```swift
class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel? {
        didSet {
            if isViewLoaded { tableView.reloadData() }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

ViewModel can be easily used as the data source of the TableView.

```swift
extension ExerciseViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        viewModel?.categories.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UITableViewCell {
        let category = viewModel?.categories[indexPath.row]
        let cell: UITableViewCell = ...
        cell.label.text = category.title
        cell.rowImage.image = category.image
        return cell
    }
}
```

##### The Grand Finale

The last piece of the puzzle is to instantiate the ViewModel and pass it to your ViewController. The best place to do it is where you present the screen.

```swift
let viewController: ExerciseViewController = ...
ViewController.viewModel = ExerciseViewModel()
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

##### Epilogue

With ViewModel in place we can now move more logic to it for example the code that gets triggered when we tap on a cell.

```swift
extension ExerciseViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        viewModel?.didTapCategory(at: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

```swift
final class ExerciseViewModel {
    let categories: [ExerciseCategory] = [ ... ]

    weak var delegate: ExerciseViewModelDelegate?

    func didTapCategory(at index: Int) {
        // do something, maybe notify a delegate?
        delegate?.viewModel(didSelect: categories[index])
    }
}
```

```swift
protocol ExerciseViewModelDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewModel(didSelect category: ExerciseCategory)
}
```